# read an zip file object by pycdf without unzipping

Tags: python, zip

I know how to open a file in a zip file without unzipping. It can be done as follows:

```
import zipfile
archive = zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zipfile, 'r')
my_zipfile = archive.open('file_01.cdf')    # "file_01.cdf" is contained in the zipfile
```

My problem is: the file "file_01.cdf" contained in the zip file is in CDF format. Normally, a CDF format file can be read as follows:

```
from spacepy import pycdf

cdf_file = pycdf.CDF(path_to_file)
data = cdf_file.copy()
```

The problem is: function `pycdf.CDF` accept argument in string format. However, I want to pass an zipfile object as an argument to `pycdf.CDF` function. (Because I don't unzip the zip file, I don't have path to file as a string). Any idea to overcome this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I know you specifically asked about doing it without unzipping but I think that's not possible (someone will correct me if I'm wrong, I hope).

You could do something like:

```
import zipfile
import os
import tempfile
import shutil

path = r'C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\test.zip' # my zip file
archive = zipfile.ZipFile(path, 'r')

tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp(dir=os.getcwd()) # create a temp folder in the working directory
archive.extract('test.txt', path=tmpdir) # extract your file to the temp folder
path_to_my_file = os.path.join(tmpdir, 'test.txt') # this is the path to the extracted file
# -------
# do stuff with your file path
# -------
print(path_to_my_file)
shutil.rmtree(tmpdir) # delete the temp folder
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but  it's not really a solution for me! I could also delete the whole unzipped folder after analyzing data in one command.